# MBA mid 2011: Artifacts on screen after wake from deep sleep

Tags: macbook-pro, sleep-wake, screen

I'm using Macbook Air (mid 2011) and there is one problem with it. After macbook waking from deep sleep, it has some "artifacts" (i don't know how to name it correctly) on the screen:

[image: Image1]
[image: Image2]

Artifacts on the top under the menu bar on the second image are always present after deep sleep, but other artifacts can be or can't be. And I don't know if this a hardware or software issue, but these artifacts were always present through every my Mac OS X update. Now I have 10.7.5 Lion.

Artifacts disappear after reboot. So I can't use deep sleep as I should. Has anybody experienced this?

Answer (score 2):

Those are very characteristic failures of a hardware nature.

- the LVDS cable that carries the signal could be faulty or loose
- the GPU could be having problems (perhaps heat related, perhaps not)
- the LCD panel could be physically failing or loose or electrically failing
- much less likely causes would be RAM, Storage or software (erase and reinstall)

I would start with contacting support in the country of sale and/or country where you are now:

- http://support.apple.com/kb/HE57

They will be able to advise you where and how to request a quote for service and then you can decide to pursue hardware repair or further troubleshoot software. Faulty software could cause this, but it's unlikely to come and go and you might waste time reinstalling the OS, clearing preferences, etc…

If the issues only happen after sleep, you might also consider a failure of the RAM or storage where the sleep image becomes corrupt or the part of the RAM that backs the GPU has problems. Again, on an Air, there are no parts that Apple recommends anyone but a trained technician to service, and they have access to additional resources and can send the diagrams to engineering if they don't have enough experience on that particular model. Most Apple store geniuses would know typical failure modes of each model since they see so many broken machines, but they don't work from home or by phone unless you have a paid support plan.

Answer (score 0):

When this happened to me it was a bad graphics card. I took it to Apple and they replaced the motherboard under warranty.

Comment: Did you have exactly these artifacts?

Comment: The were very similar.

Comment: There were also different app's crashes while using macbook after this state. Have you got these crashes too maybe?

Comment: Take it to Apple and let them have a look at it.

Comment: The problem is that there is no Apple in Russia

Comment: I don't think anybody else can help you. You can try resetting PRAM, Power manager reset, etc.. The usual troubleshooting tips, but I'm pretty sure it's a hardware problem. You could also try turning off deep sleep.

Comment: Bad GPU is the most likely cause to having those two distinct failure modes on the same mac. Good call. Also, the logic board replaced RAM, Processor and GPU since they all are mounted on the same part assembly.